# Does Windows return command line switch character?

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-arguments

In Windows, command line options are preceded by `/`, sometimes by `-`. Is there a way to query Windows for this character? In MS-DOS, there was a `SWITCHAR` setting in `config.sys`. Is there a similar setting or system resource which can be obtained from Windows? Or should my command-line app simply use `/` or `-` without looking anywhere?

Comment: It's application defined.  Use whatever command line syntax floats your boat, but probably a good idea to support both for convention.

Comment: @PeterHuene – I'm currently using both. Please put this claim into an answer including its source and I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there was ever a way that this was exposed externally.  Perhaps some DOS 2.0 commands checked it, but nothing else did.

> "SWITCHAR was never really supported, even by DOS commands (let alone third-party programs)." [[source](http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0295.HTM)]

I assume third-party programs were expected to parse config.sys themselves.  I don't think there was any Windows support to get this particular value.  (A Larry Osterman blog post talks about the [history of SWITCHAR](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2005/06/24/432386.aspx?PageIndex=2) and hints that there might have been OS support for it once upon a time.)

Best practice is to allow either.

Comment: In MS-DOS the 0x37 DOS call would get and set the switch character. I am not sure this was documented. My recollection is that the utilities supplied with MS-DOS called this function, but third-party tools frequently did not and hard-coded the switch character.